# Как выровнять элементы на футера по центру

Tags: html5, css3

Не  получается сделать элементы относительно родительского блока (padding: 16px 100px 16px 75px) и что бы контент был в одну линию.[image: Этот блок выше уровня]

```css
.footer-boottom,
.bot_mnu a {
  background-color: #a4a4a4;
  color: #3e3e3e;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.bot_mnu li {
  border-left: 1px solid #146481;
  padding-left: 13px;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

.fot-social {}

.footer-boottom {
  padding: 16px 100px 16px 75px;
}

.footer-boottom li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.social-bottom {
  text-align: right;
  color: #727272;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid footer-boottom">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="fot-social">
      <div class="col-md-6 copy-r">
        <span>&#169; 2015 LOREM LOREM LOREM</span>
        <ul class="bot_mnu">
          <li><a href="#">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SITE BY: KEY WEB CONCEPTS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6  social-bottom">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.ru.html 2) https://webref.ru/   3)http://mybootstrap.ru/

Comment: Тебе нужно только сделать их в строчку. Или всё остальное как на картинке тоже ?

Comment: @ codename0082016, нужно что бы левый блок copyright-та был на одном уровне с блоком где иконки.

Comment: @ codename0082016
(https://pp.userapi.com/c637926/v637926512/4dfdf/mWsBZ18H3uw.jpg)
Как сделать чтобы левый блок был на одном уровне с иконками справа

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Достаточно добавить следующий код:

```
.fot-social {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.footer-boottom,
.bot_mnu a {
  background-color: #a4a4a4;
  color: #3e3e3e;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.bot_mnu {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bot_mnu li {
  border-left: 1px solid #146481;
  padding-left: 13px;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

.fot-social {}

.footer-boottom {
  padding: 16px 100px 16px 75px;
}

.footer-boottom li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.social-bottom {
  text-align: right;
  color: #727272;
}

.copy-r {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 
  
  <div class="container-fluid footer-boottom">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="fot-social">
      <div class="col-md-8 copy-r">
        <span>&#169; 2015 LOREM LOREM LOREM</span>
        <ul class="bot_mnu">
          <li><a href="#">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SITE BY: KEY WEB CONCEPTS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4  social-bottom">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Добавила `.copy-r` `padding-top`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.footer-boottom,
.bot_mnu a {
  background-color: #a4a4a4;
  color: #3e3e3e;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.bot_mnu li {
  border-left: 1px solid #146481;
  padding-left: 13px;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

.fot-social {}

.footer-boottom {
  padding: 16px 100px 16px 75px;
}

.footer-boottom li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.social-bottom {
  text-align: right;
  color: #727272;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid footer-boottom">
  <div >
    <div class="fot-social">
      <div class="col-md-6 copy-r">
        <div class="bot_mnu">
        <span>&#169; 2015 LOREM LOREM LOREM</span>

          <li><a href="#">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SITE BY: KEY WEB CONCEPTS</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6  social-bottom">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```